# CSB inquality: is $\|x\|^2\|y\|^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2$ a square in any obvious way?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inequality

Suppose $x=(x_1,x_2),y = (y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. I noticed that
\begin{align*}
\|x\|^2 \|y\|^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2 &=
x_1^2y_1^2 + x_1^2 y_2^2 + x_2^2 y_1^2 + x_2^2 y_2 ^2 - (x_1^2 y_1^2 + 2 x_1 y_1 x_2 y_2 + x_2^2 y_2^2) \\
&=(x_1 y_2)^2 - 2x_1 y_2 x_2 y_1 + (x_2 y_2)^2 \\
&=(x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)^2
\end{align*}
which proves the CSB inequality in dimension two. This begs the question:

> If $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n),y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is there a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n;y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ such that $ \|x\|^2 \|y\|^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2 = p^2$?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I strongly recommend having a look at Steele's book *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class*. [link](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/CSMC_index.html)

Comment: Apparently CSB Inequality = Cauchy-Schwarz-Buniakovski Ineq. ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah.

Comment: This is related to [Hilbert's 17th problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem).  Artin showed that every nonnegative-valued polynomial is a finite sum of rational squares, hence "obviously" nonnegative.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No (it is not a square of a polynomial for $n \ge 3$), but the right generalization, proving that it is nonnegative, is that it is a *sum of squares*.

For instance, for $n = 3$, 
$$
\begin{align*}
\|x\|^2 \|y\|^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2 &= (x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)^2 + (x_2y_3-x_3y_2)^2 + (x_3y_1 - x_1y_3)^2,
\end{align*}
$$

and in general
$$
\begin{align*}
\|x\|^2 \|y\|^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2 &= \sum_{i < j}(x_iy_{j} - x_{j}y_{i})^2
\end{align*}
$$

---

This is easy to prove algebraically: the left hand side is

$$
\begin{align*}
\|x\|^2 \|y\|^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2 
&= (\sum{x_i^2}\sum{y_j^2}) - (\sum{x_iy_i})^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=j}{x_i^2 y_j^2} + \sum_{i\neq j}{x_i^2y_j^2} - \sum_{i=j}{x_iy_ix_iy_i} - \sum_{i\neq j}{x_iy_ix_jy_j} \\ 
&= \sum_{i<j}{(x_i^2 y_j^2 + x_j^2 y_i^2)} - \sum_{i<j}{2x_iy_ix_jy_j} \\
&= \sum_{i<j}{(x_i^2 y_j^2 - 2x_iy_jx_jy_i + x_j^2y_i^2)} \\
&= \sum_{i < j}(x_iy_{j} - x_{j}y_{i})^2
\end{align*}
$$

This identity is known as [Lagrange's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

---

This also shows that the left hand size is zero when for all pairs $(i,j)$, we have $x_iy_j - x_jy_i = 0$, i.e., $$\frac{y_i}{x_i} = \frac{y_j}{x_j}$$ (let's assume the $x_j$s are nonzero, for now), which is another way of saying that one vector is a multiple of the other, i.e., equality holds in the inequality when the two vectors are parallel.

---

For the former (showing that it is not the square of a polynomial), consider for instance $n=3$. If $\|x\|^2 \|y\|^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2$ is the square of a polynomial $p(x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3)$, then we can write the polynomial as $qx_1 + r$, where $q = q(x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3)$ and $r = r(x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3)$ are polynomials that don't depend on $x_1$. As $(qx_1+r)^2 = q^2x_1^2 + 2qrx_1 + r^2$, the coefficient of $x_1^2$ should be a square, but the coefficient is $y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2 - y_1^2 = y_2^2 + y_3^2$ (or in general, $\sum_{i=2}^{n}y_i^2$), which is not the square of a polynomial. (Proved similarly: if it is the square of $qy_2 + r$, then comparing coefficients of $y_2^2$ gives $q \equiv 1$, and comparing coefficents of $y_2$ gives $r \equiv 0$, which is not consistent with the rest.)

---

As Erick Wong points out in the comments, this is related to (the solution of) [Hilbert's seventeenth problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem), which says that any polynomial that takes only nonnegative values can be written as a sum of squares of rational functions. If we only care about representations as [sum of squares of *polynomials*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_SOS), any nonnegative polynomial can be approximated as closely as desired with a sum of squares of polynomials. See e.g. the book [*Positive Polynomials and Sums of Squares*](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/surv-146) ([preview](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/surv-146-prev.pdf)).

Comment: Are you sure? I don't understand why terms like $x_i y_j$ for $\vert j - i \vert > 1$ wouldn't appear in the general form for $n > 3$.

Comment: @roger: Sorry, you are right... was fixing it when I saw your comment.

Comment: ok now I find it plausible :).

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks this is very nice to know. I think when I first saw the CSB inequality it was in the context of Hilbert spaces. I had no idea there was such a nice simple algebraic proof in finite dimension.

Answer (score 5):

$\sum x_i^2\sum y_i^2-(\sum x_iy_i)^2$

$=\sum x_i^2y_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j} x_i^2y_j^2-\sum x_i^2y_i^2-\sum_{i\neq j} x_iy_ix_jy_j$

$=\sum_{i<j} (x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2$

Comment: Some words never hurt nobody!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Try that without the double negative.

Comment: Double, triple and more negative are advanced, nice features of well developed and beautiful languages, like spanish, russian and wooly-wooly (which, if it existed, would be widely known and spoken in some 1,000 tiny islands in Micronesia). In fact, it should have been: "Don't some words never didn't hurt anybody?"

Answer (score 5):

When $n\ge3$, $\|x\|^2\|y\|^2 - \langle x,y\rangle^2$ is not the square of any polynomial $p(x,y)$. Keep all entries other than $x_1$ fixed and let
\begin{align*}
q(x_1) &= \|x\|^2\|y\|^2 - \langle x,y\rangle^2,\\
\Rightarrow q\,'(x_1) &= 2(x_1 \|y\|^2 - y_1\langle x,y\rangle)
\end{align*}
If $q$ is a squared polynomial, some zero of $q\,'$ must be a zero of $q$. However, when $x=(x_1,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $y=(1,0,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$, we have $q\,'(x_1)=2x_1$ and $q(x_1)=2(x_1^2+1)-x_1^2$. So, the only zero of $q\,'$ is $x_1=0$, but $q(0)=2\neq0$. Therefore $q$ is not a squared polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

CSB inquality can be generalized: Gramian's matrix determinant is equal or greater than a zero. And equality means linear dependence of system of vectors. In case of two vectors $u$ and $v$, we have:

$$ 0 \leqslant
\begin{vmatrix}
\langle u,u \rangle & \langle u,v \rangle \\
\langle v,u \rangle & \langle v,v \rangle \\
\end{vmatrix}
 = \|u\|^2 \cdot \|v\|^2 - \langle u,v \rangle^2 $$

So, it's another proof of CSB.